# Routing in ASP.NET Web Forms with Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, routes, webforms

I am working on an ASP.NET web forms application that is using Forms Authentication.  The problem is, it ignores my route and redirects to the login.aspx page.

I have the following route setup:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("/locale", "{locale}", "~/shorturl/transfer.aspx", 
            false, 
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "locale", "[a-z]{2}" } });
```

If I use the following url:  http://server/minneapolis it goes to the login page.  If I add the following to the Web.Config, then it "works" and goes to the transfer.aspx page.

```
<location path="minneapolis"> 
    <system.web> 
      <authorization> 
        <allow users="*"/> 
      </authorization> 
    </system.web> 
 </location>
```

I don't want to have to add all of the locales to the web.config, seems to defeat the purpose.

I can also change the route to (notice I added "/loc/"):

```
    routes.MapPageRoute("/locale", "/loc/{locale}", "~/shorturl/transfer.aspx", 
            false, 
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "locale", "[a-z]{2}" } });
```

After that I can change the Web.Config location path to loc (location path="loc") and it works, but I'd really prefer to have it at the root.  Is there any way to do this?

It's .NET v4 and I have to support IIS 7 and IIS 7.5

Comment: Is your  http://server/minneapolis path a secured one...I mean should the user be authenticated in order to get to  http://server/minneapolis...? if possible can you post your page's code behind?

Comment: I don't want it to be secure, but depending how it's configured it is or isn't.  Which page do you want to see the code behind for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it. Authorization is url based and the authorization module seems to check the **source** url rather than the destination url when it determines how to authorize the request.

Like 6 months just failed exactly the same way as you did in one of my projects. I ended up with the solution you propose - my routed requests were put in a "subfolder" and I created a local `web.config` with `authorization allow users=*`.

If there's a way around this, I would also like to hear how it should be done.